# Spring Annotations: Why @Required doesn't work when class is @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, autowired, spring-annotations

When I have a class as follows:

```
public class MyConfig {
    private Integer threshold;

    @Required
    public void setThreshold(Integer threshold) { this.threshold = threshold; }
}
```

And I use it as follows:

```
public class Trainer {
    @Autowired
    private MyConfig configuration;

    public void setConfiguration(MyConfig configuration) { this.configuration = configuration; }
}
```

And initialize the Trainer in the xml context as follows:

```
<bean id="myConfiguration" class="com.xxx.config.MyConfig">
        <!--<property name="threshold" value="33"/>-->
</bean>
```

For some reason the @Required annotation doesn't apply, and The context starts without a problem (It should have thrown an exception saying the field threshold is required...).

Why is that??

Comment: Check whether you have configured `RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`. Otherwise `@Required` will not be scanned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might have missed a configuration.

> Simply applying the **@Required** annotation will not enforce the property
>   checking, you also need to register an
>   **RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor** to aware of the **@Required**
>   annotation in bean configuration file.

## The RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor can be enabled in two ways.

1. Include `<context:annotation-config/>`

   Add Spring context and  in bean configuration file.

   ```
   <beans 
   ...
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   ...
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd" >
   ...
   <context:annotation-config />
   ...
   </beans>
   ```
2. Include **RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor**

   Include ‘`RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`’ directly in bean configuration file.

> ```
> <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
>   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">
>
> <bean 
> class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
> ```

Comment: I don't understand why I need this bean only when @Autowired is used, but it works! thanks.